# Rails nested association & multiple collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm having some issues updating my association tables when using multiple select.

I have three tables, `portrait` `portrait_tags` and `tags`

(The tags stores the names of my tag names (traditional, inspirational, community etc))

My desired outcome is that the 'multiple select field' will add the tags to the portrait_tag table based on the Tag.all tag_id value. Currently this seems to insert only one field and the tag_id in the portrait_tag table is NULL, then when I return to the edit page the multiple select is duplicated.

**Params**

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"j+Obhq9u+mvOKYnj4+TAGy+be8s3AbZlMvuyKiot5iyKqjMyFAcs23PjbQjOTjwl6aRBx1M5lmYRZzTjOeDTJA==", "portrait"=>{"portrait_tags_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"tag_id"=>["", "1", "2"]}}}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"72"}
```

**Tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :portraits, through: :portrait_tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :portraits

end
```

**Portrait.rb**

```
class Portrait < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :portrait_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :portrait_tags

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :portrait_tags

end
```

**Portrait_tag.rb**

```
class PortraitTag < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :portrait
  belongs_to :tag

end
```

**Edit.html.haml**

```
%h1 Edit Portrait
= form_for [:admin, @portraits], :html => { :method => :put } do |f|

  - if flash[:system].present?
    - flash[:system].each do |e|
      %div= e

  - if flash[:notice].present?
    %div= flash[:notice]

  = f.fields_for :portrait_tags do |a|
    = a.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}

  = f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

**PortraitController**

```
class Admin::PortraitsController < ApplicationController

    def edit
       @portraits = Portrait.where(artist_id: 33, id: params[:id]).take
       @portraits.portrait_tags.build

    end

    def update

      @portrait = Portrait.where(artist_id: 33, id: params[:id]).take


      if @portrait.update(portrait_params)

        p portrait_params

      else
        flash[:system] = @portrait.errors.full_messages
        p @portrait.errors.full_messages

        render :edit
      end

    end

    private
      def portrait_params
        # Permit our attributes
        params.require(:portrait).permit(:id, portrait_tags_attributes: [:id, :tag_id => [] ])

      end



end
```

**portrait_tags table**

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | portrait_id | tag_id |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

**portraits table**

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | artist_id | artist_image |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

**tags table**

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+
| id |   name    |   portrait_tag_id  |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= collection_select(:portrait_tag, :tag_ids, 
              Tag.all(:order=>"name ASC"), 
              :id, :name, {:selected => @portraits.tag_ids, :include_blank => true}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Could you explain a little why? I'm struggling figuring this out!

Comment: Thanks Atul,

If I have another field within the form_for how can I pass param for multiple?

    params.require(:portrait).permit(:id, :artist_image)
     params.require(:portrait_tag).permit(:id, :tag_ids => [])